# Node: Best processes to redirect + pass external api results to new page on search

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have a personal website where I can search for a specific id of something and get information about it on a new page. Currently, clicking search will redirect the window (using client side javascript) to this 'info' page, then when this new page loads, (localhost/example/2 where the given id is 2), the client side javascript will make an api call to my node server, which then makes an call to an external api (I probably could just directly call the external api from the client-side - i'm not sure what the standard is). This external api feeds back data to my server which then feeds back data to the client side javascript, which then updates elements on the webpage using jquery to show the collected information about the item with that id.

Ideally, I would like to change it so that initially searching for an id (i.e clicking the search button) calls the external api, and upon receiving the data, redirects the user to the new page but also passes the data alongside it (I have converted my html files to jade for this reason). Thus the user will have all the data loaded on the new page as soon as the page loads, and if there is an error (eg. provided non-existent id), the server can redirect to an 'error' page without first going to the information page briefly (currently it goes to the info page, calls the api, gets the error and redirects - so it shows the info page for ~1-2 seconds).

Unfortunately, I can't find much luck in seeing how to redirect and pass variables to the jade file. I'm unsure if this is even the right approach for a problem of this context. Maybe it is better to be calling the api once navigating to the info page - however I feel like it's better (?) to be using a template to display information that is dependent on the id rather than replacing the html with javascript on the success of the api call.

Does anyone have any insight into what approach they would normally take to tackle a problem of this nature. One issue with my ideal route is that I would need to find a way of persisting the variables passed to the jade template when the info page is refreshed, but I'm sure that is an easier task.

Thanks in advance for any help and/or insight.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cookies, Session Storage are a means of keeping data on a refresh.  If you're using url scheme with /id/ then don't use ajax to get the data, call the api internally and pass the variables to the jade template using `res.render(template,pagedata)` which then whatever object keys in `pagedata` is accessible to the template through `!{keyName}` or `#{keyName}` (learn the difference!!!) Additionally you can pass locals to the jade file using something like `app.locals._ = _;` which is what I use to include lodash functions while compling the pug/jade into html.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Would this be best to do through redirecting the client first (the search button click would solely change window.location to the info page) and then including this api call in the GET for the /info/:id page. I would need to make it so the page isn't rendered until the external apis (there's actually two apis that i call to get all the information) are done. I assume this is where promises come into play?